# Blazor EditForm 'model is a type, which is not valid in the given context'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, blazor

I have this simple Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BlazorApp.Data
{
    public class DataModel
    {

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 500, ErrorMessage = "Width needs to be above 1m and below 500m")]
        public int Width { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 500, ErrorMessage = "Length needs to be above 1m and below 500m")]
        public int Length { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 500, ErrorMessage = "Height needs to be above 1m and below 500m")]
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my Razor file, which I am trying to use the model in:

```
<EditForm Model="@BlazorApp.Data.DataModel" OnValidSubmit="@Handle"> // ERROR OCCURS HERE 
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />

<InputText id="width" @bind-Value="BlazorApp.Data.DataModel.Width" />
<InputText id="length" @bind-Value="BlazorApp.Data.DataModel.Length" />
<InputText id="height" @bind-Value="BlazorApp.Data.DataModel.Height" />
```

```
@code {
    private BlazorApp.Data.DataModel model = new BlazorApp.Data.DataModel();

    private void Handle()
    {

    }
}
```

The error occurs `Model="@BlazorApp.Data.DataModel"` and obviously within the `@bind-values' of each form. Whys this the case, I don't think the namspace Data is a type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Model="@BlazorApp.Data.DataModel"` should be `Model="@model"`.

You need to reference the name of the variable (`model`) aka the variable holding all of the data for the form, not the name of it's type.

Your `InputText`'s should also have something like `@bind-Value="model.Height"`. Again, they need to reference the specific variable, not the field in the data type.

Comment: I'm confused to how `@model` references my custom `DataModel` class though?

Comment: You defined "private BlazorApp.Data.DataModel model". This means the variable "model" is structured using your "DataModel" class

Comment: And the `@` is optional here. Leave it out. `Model="model"`